# Back Button gets Disabled on IE 7,8 for an ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

In an ASP.NET 3.5 website we are noticing that the back button is not working properly. If the user does several postbacks (say 10 times), and than starts pressing back button - the back button gets disabled before the user gets through all the pages. The site does not use AJAX.net.

I can reproduce the issue on IE 7 and 8 almost always. The problem seems to be with some sort of limit IE has on History Cache for a given tab/instance. In the tests I did the post request to the server are large - around 83k, and the responses are are round 300k. It seems that with these request sizes the history does not hold more than 4 items. The moment I get to the 5 post, the first item i had selected is dropped.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page that reproduces this problem?

Comment: is not a public application :(
i will see if i can build a demo for it

Comment: There are lots of vague complaints of this on many user forums all over the net.  If you can provide a solid repro, that would help everyone greatly.

Comment: I did a quick HTML demo page which you can download here: http://drop.io/ietestbackbutton

just place it on a local server, or even open directly on IE. You will see the issue by clicking at the second link several times and looking at the history.length counter on the page - and the back button in ie.

Comment: Old post, but I'm running into this issue now.  It does seem related to the POST request size as in our case it happens when attaching an image.  With a small image, the back button works.  With a large image, the back button doesn't do anything and it becomes disabled.

Comment: Still haven't narrowed this down, but in our case it appears to be related to the timing, and not directly to the POST request size.  If we POST before the page has completed loading, then the back button doesn't work.  When waiting for the page to fully load then doing the POST, everything works as expected.  In our case, a large POST request size (bigger image, ViewState, etc.) caused a large POST *response* which made it easier to click a button on the page before it all loaded.  I don't have a solution, but hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: @timeitquery did you managed to find any solution of this back button getting disabled in IE8 ? I have a asp.net mvc app where I've same issues.

Answer (score 3):

We experienced the same issue. We would load a particular page, and after about 5 seconds, IE8 browser history would get blown away. As a result, history.back() would not work, and IE8 back button would not work. Eventually, we narrowed it down to the large "viewstate" (In our case, the size of the "viewstate" was like 600KB due to "Repeater" control having "viewstate" enabled).  When we disabled the "viewstate" on the "Repeater" control, the size came down to about 11KB. Now, both IE8 back button and history.back() work well.

Answer (score 0):

The user has to have gone back to the first page; that's the only way I know of to disable the back button in IE (or any other browser).  Did the application open another tab; that could cause confusion on how far the back button will go.

Also, is the user getting prompted, by IE, to reapply changes when they hit the back button?  I know that is an issue with ASP.NET sites in general and that could cause problems in the browser with using the back button.

Comment: well in my case i can reproduce the issue on IE 7 always. The problem might be with some sort of limit IE has. The post request are large - 83k, and the responses are 300k. It seems that this numbers the history does not hold more than 4 items. The moment i go on the 5 post, the first item is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.replace
or

history.forward();

in the head

Comment: i do not have it on any of the JS libraries I wrote. I am using the AJAX.NET libraries in the page, not using update panel - but i am using it for a modal window.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IE that has manifested in one way or another since (at least) IE6.  The bug is in the TravelLog code.  It sometimes gets confused.

Comment: Anyway to avoid this bug besides cutting the POST size?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I'm not even certain is related to POST size.