# Browser back button is becoming disabled/grayed out all of a sudden

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've been working on this project (website, ASP.NET, VB.NET, IE8 [no choice on that]) for almost 2 years with no problems with the back button. I use mostly SQLDataSources, GridViews, and DetailsViews. All of a sudden, two weeks ago, the browser's back button becomes grayed out when I click on a link or button; it seems to be happening to any buttons or links. And of course, it doesn't happen in Chrome. Too bad I can't change the browser the company defaults to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4251142/130611 is the page size large?

Comment: The pages consists of one or two gridviews, at most. There's one page with a lot of datasources, each selecting one field from a db view, but it didn't happen with it, either. These are small pages, paged gridviews, not a lot of code-behind. It just started happening.

Comment: I mean, if you do a view source, how big is the html? What browser and version number are you having trouble with?

Comment: I tried one and it was 152K. But I'm on a different computer today and (IE8) doesn't have the problem... I guess this is a problem with my computer only. I never thought to try it on a different computer. Thanks!